# Select all tags inside div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got the tag structure below. This is repeated 9 times over the page. I want it that when I hover over one of the 9 'itemInfo' divs it will change all the text colors to white (including links). How can I select all of these using jQuery? See my attempt below.

```
<div class="row itemInfo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns itemImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/185/abstract/">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns itemDetails"> 
            <h3><a href="#">title</a></h3>
            <p class="quiet">submitted by <a href="#">designer</a></p>                   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My attempt:

```
$(".itemInfo").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('h3 a').addClass('itemInfoActive');
    $(this).find('p').addClass('itemInfoActive');
    $(this).find('p a').addClass('itemInfoActive');
    return false;
```

Comment: Why does what you have not work for you?

Comment: you have a missing `});` at the end of your `hover` function...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".itemInfo").mouseenter(function() {
    $('a,p,h3',this).addClass('itemInfoActive');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the universal selector for this:

```
$(".itemInfo").hover(function() {    
    $(this).find('*').addClass('itemInfoActive');
});
```

Comment: Yo bruv, you are missing the `.parent` `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/E8uws/ **or** use `mouseout` or `mouseover` => http://jsfiddle.net/yUf4Q/

And if you keen to read more: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Rest should help your need `:)`
**Code**

```
$(function() {
    $(".itemInfo").hover(function() {
            $(this).parent().find('*').css('color', 'red');
    });
});​
```

**Extra code**

```
$(function() {
    $(".itemInfo").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('*').css('color', 'red');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('*').css('color', 'black');

    });
});​
```